# How to Get another value in another table using a dynamic call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I currently have this query with an array that outputs the variables within using a dynamic input in my form `(term)`, this creates a Dynamic Search with auto complete to fill in all of the details for a product.

```
    $return_arr = array();
$param = $_GET["term"];
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM crd_jshopping_products WHERE `name_en-GB` REGEXP '^$param'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    //$row_array['category_id']  = $row ['category_id'];

$row_array['product_id'] = $row['product_id'];
    $row_array['product_names']  = $row['name_en-GB'];
    $row_array['jshop_code_prod'] = $row['product_ean'];
    $row_array['_ext_price_html']  = number_format($row['product_price'],2);
if (!empty($row['product_thumb_image']) AND isset($row['product_thumb_image'])){
$row_array['image'] = $row['product_thumb_image'];      
}else {
    $row_array['image'] = 'noimage.gif';    
}
    array_push( $return_arr, $row_array);
}
mysql_close($conn);
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Unfortunately I also need to get the `category_id` which is not in the same `table`, I have tried to modify my `query` as such, but to no avail:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM crd_jshopping_products WHERE `name_en-GB` REGEXP '^$param' AND `crd_jshopping_products_to_categories`  = `product_id` ");
```

What step am I missing here ? The `product_id's` match in both `tables`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query instead and try to understand what I have written in it:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        p.*,
        c.category_id
    FROM
        crd_jshopping_products as p
        INNER JOIN crd_jshopping_products_to_categories as c
            ON p.product_id = c.product_id
    WHERE
        `p.name_en-GB` REGEXP '^$param'
");
```

This means:

> **SELECT:**
>   Give me everything from **p** and the category_id from **c**.
>
> **FROM:**
>   Do this from rows in the tables crd_jshopping_products (**referred to as p**) and crd_jshopping_products_to_categories (**referred to as c**), where the rows match on the count of **p**.product_id is the same as **c**.product_id.
>
> **WHERE:**
>   Only return the rows where **p**.name_en-GB REGEXP '^$param'.

Comment: Thank you nl-x - for both the query and the in-depth explanation, I have needed one for quite some time! I will test it immediately!

Comment: I had to add"`" to the p.name_en-GB around name_en-GB because of the hyphen, just for others who may try this or similar.
Thank you nl-x it was spot on and now I have a great refference for future queries!